# Dynamically loaded image use as background for containing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I've got a complex dynamic image gallery, images loaded by php, layed out by jquery... and what I need to do, is use whatever image is loaded into the lightbox as the background for the containing div (in addition to displaying like normal)... I cant really add a class to the image itself, but I can target it via .lightbox img

any help is appreciated:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="lightbox">
<img src="image.jpg"><!--php dynamic loaded image-->    
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us your PHP code, and explain what you've already tried, and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can just modify the `background-image` css attribute for your main container, using the source of the image you loaded.](http://jsfiddle.net/mgcshLbn/)

```
var $img = $('.lightbox img');
var $container = $('#main-container');
$container.css('background-image', 'url(' + $img.attr('src') + ')');
```

Comment: thats awesome and works  - I was able to implement that into the code;